# The given key was not present in the dictionary running tests in parallel with specflow c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, specflow

I'm trying to pass the value from SceanrioContext to steps definitions in my tests with following way. I have Hooks class where _scenarioContext["lambda"] value is successfully retrieved and kept:

```
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        private static IUnityContainer _container;
        private static object locker = new object();
        private static ThreadLocal<Lambda> _lambda = new ThreadLocal<Lambda>();
        private static ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        private static ScenarioContextSafe _scenarioContextSafe;
        
        public Hooks(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, ScenarioContextSafe scenarioContextSafe)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext; 
            _scenarioContextSafe = scenarioContextSafe;    
        }

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void ConfigurationSetUp()
        {
            Log.Info("Recreate S3 bucket");
            AmazonS3Helper.RecreateBucketAsync().Wait();
            Log.Info("Setup Configuration");
            _container = new UnityContainer();
            _objectContainer = new ObjectContainer();
            _container.RegisterType<ISettings, TestSettings>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.RegisterType<IAmazonServiceFactory, AmazonServiceFactory>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.RegisterType<IPackageCollection, PackageCollection>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.RegisterType<ILambdaCollection, LambdaCollection>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.RegisterType<IStepFunctionCollection, StepFunctionCollection>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.RegisterType<IS3BucketCollection, S3BucketCollection>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled);
            _container.Resolve<ResoucesLoader>().Load();
        }        

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void DeployTransformStyleLambda()
        {
            var lambdasAll = _container.Resolve<ILambdaCollection>();
            _scenarioContext["lambda"] = lambdasAll.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == TransformStyle);
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (!((Lambda)_scenarioContext["lambda"]).Exists)
                {
                    ((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"]).DeployAsync().Wait();
                    ((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"]).ReloadConfigurationAsync().Wait();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in **MyTestsSteps1** class the value for **((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"])** is successfully invoked but and in **MyTestsSteps2** class I get the error message: **The given key 'lambda' was not present in the dictionary** when **two tests are executed in parallel**.
*NOTE: Both tests are passing successfully running in single thread one by one* though

```
[Binding]
public class MyTestsSteps1
{
 
    private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public MyTestsSteps1(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [Given(@"test me")]
    public void TestMe()
    {
        
            ((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"]).InvokeAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request)).Wait();
        
    }
```

And:

```
[Binding]
public class MyTestsSteps2
        {
     
            private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
    
            public MyTestsSteps2(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
            {
                _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
            }
    
            [Given(@"again test me")]
            public void TestMe()
            {
                
                    ((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"]).InvokeAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request)).Wait();
                
            }
```

**UPDATE:** Added ScenarioContextSafe class with ConcurrentDictionary implementation

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


{
    public class ScenarioContextSafe
    {
        private static ScenarioContextSafe _current;
        private static readonly object Locker = new object();

        public static ScenarioContextSafe Current
        {
            get
            {
                lock (Locker)
                {
                    return _current ?? (_current = new ScenarioContextSafe());
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Reset()
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                _current = null;
            }
        }

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _concurrentDictionary =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            _concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
        }

        public void Set(object value, string key)
        {
            if (!_concurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                _concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
            else
                _concurrentDictionary[key] = value;
        }

        public void Remove(string key)
        {
            object result;
            _concurrentDictionary.TryRemove(key, out result);
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            object result;
            _concurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result);
            return (T) result;
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(string key)
        {
            return _concurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

    }
}
```

Now BeforeScenario method in hooks looks like:

```
[BeforeScenario]
    public void DeployTransformStyleLambda()
    {
        var lambdasAll = _container.Resolve<ILambdaCollection>();
       _scenarioContextSafe.Add("lambda", lambdasAll.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == TransformStyle));
        if (!_scenarioContextSafe.Get<Lambda>("lambda").Exists)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                _scenarioContextSafe.Get<Lambda>("lambda").DeployAsync().Wait();
                _scenarioContextSafe.Get<Lambda>("lambda").ReloadConfigurationAsync().Wait();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Still while running tests in parallel and when I refer to _scenarioContextSafe.Get("lambda").InvokeAsync() in steps first test is passing but the second one fails with the error : **System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: It sounds like `_scenarioContext` is being modified during the run. You can't modify a dictionary if there are other threads reading it. Try using a `ConcurrentDictionary` and see if the problem goes away. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Enigmativity, i've updated the question. I tried ConcurrentDictionary  but still getting the error in second thread as `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` once I refer to `_scenarioContextSafe.Get<Lambda>("lambda")`

Comment: This might be an artifact of copying and pasting code, but your Hooks and step definition classes need the `[Binding]` attribute. Do you have that on each of those classes?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, yep, thx , i do have [Binding] attr. for steps and hooks. Updated the post

Comment: Maybe `lambdasAll.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == TransformStyle);` is returning a null value in the `[BeforeScenario]`? Try changing it to `.Single(...)` or `.First(...)`, so it throws an exception if it cannot find anything that matches the lambda expression.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, i double checked the test is failing with the error above on this line `((Lambda) _scenarioContext["lambda"]).InvokeAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request)).Wait();` from `MyTestSteps2` class. `lambdasAll.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == TransformStyle)`  works fine for both threads and lambda is not null

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've got the reason why parallel test execution didn't work for me. That's so silly from my side...because of scenarioContext being `STATIC`!!!!! (line #4 and line #5 in Hooks class). It should not be static... that's it)) keep it as `private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;`

Comment: Oh, geez. I completely missed that, too. One little keyword and things go sideways. Gotta love programming!

Comment: In fact, I would recommend making all members of your `Hooks` class instance members rather than static.